# How to access parent object's other properties without accessing parent reference directly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This problem has been bothering me for a long time since I meet it in a project.

In JavaScript, it's easy to access a nested object through `.` notation. Is there any way to access parent object in a nested object?

Take a look at code below:

```
function Parent() {
  this.foo = new Foo;
  this.bar = new Bar;
}

function Foo () {
  this.sayHi = function () {
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
}

function Bar() {
  this.callFoosMethod = function () {
    // should call object foo's sayHi method and log 'Hello World'
  }
}

var parent = new Parent;
parent.bar.callFoosMethod(); // => should log 'Hello World'
```

parent has two child objects `foo` and `bar`, and in `bar` object's `callFoosMethod`, I need to access parent's `foo` object's `sayHi` method, but the `foo` nesting in `parent` knows nothing about its parent object.

Is there any way to access parent object in a nested object Or there is actually no solution to this problem in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No, there is not.

There is a composition relation. If you want to access the 'parent' you have to pass a reference explicitly. That's practice.

Now a word about "why":

A 'sub object' can be a sub-object of multiple objects:

```
var parent = new Parent;
var o = parent.bar;
o.bar.callFoosMethod(); // but o doesn't have a foo
```

This also creates issues with architecture. Circular structures are [generally bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references) and the way objects communicate has to be as straightforward as possible.

If they need to talk it *has* to be through the parent, the `Bar` is not even aware of the fact there is a `Foo` there.

#### Workarounds

---

Although this is bad practice (high coupling, wrong place for responsibility, etc) if you *must* you can do:

```
function Parent() {
  this.foo = new Foo(this);
  this.bar = new Bar(this);
}

function Foo (parent) {
  this.sayHi = function () {
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
}

function Bar(parent) {
  this.callFoosMethod = function () {
       parent.foo.sayHi(); // BAD DESIGN WARNING!
  }
}
```

Again, this is *really* bad design. It *completely* violates the single responsibility principle, separation of concerns and clear communication. It generally indicates a design problem. Avoid it unless you're absolutely sure it's what you need.

Comment: (Side note: You can also hack around this by a proxy or a getter but they are even worse since they are even less explicit here)

Answer (score 1):

you can modify your function callFoosMethod to accept Foo object as an argument. then invoke the

sayHi in it.

```
function Parent() {
  this.foo = new Foo;
  this.bar = new Bar;
}

function Foo () {
  this.sayHi = function () {
    console.log('Hello World');
  }
}

function Bar() {
  this.callFoosMethod = function (obj) {
    // should call object foo's sayHi method and log 'Hello World'
      obj.sayHi();
  }
}

var parent = new Parent;
parent.bar.callFoosMethod(parent.foo); // => should log 'Hello World'
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RgTLP/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Benjamin; if you need to do Foo things from Bar, why isn't Foo a member of Bar?  If the parent class needed to execute a Foo method, it could do so via Bar, rather than making Bar too aware of where it stands in the hierarchy.